# RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ScriptRunner.scriptThread'

Tags: python, streamlit

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

st.write("""
# Simple Iris Flower Prediction App
This app predicts the **Iris flower** type!
""")

st.sidebar.header('User Input Parameters')

def user_input_features():
    sepal_length = st.sidebar.slider('Sepal length', 4.3, 7.9, 5.4)
    sepal_width = st.sidebar.slider('Sepal width', 2.0, 4.4, 3.4)
    petal_length = st.sidebar.slider('Petal length', 1.0, 6.9, 1.3)
    petal_width = st.sidebar.slider('Petal width', 0.1, 2.5, 0.2)
    data = {'sepal_length': sepal_length,
            'sepal_width': sepal_width,
            'petal_length': petal_length,
            'petal_width': petal_width}
    features = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
    return features

df = user_input_features()

st.subheader('User Input parameters')
st.write(df)

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
Y = iris.target

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(X, Y)

prediction = clf.predict(df)
prediction_proba = clf.predict_proba(df)

st.subheader('Class labels and their corresponding index number')
st.write(iris.target_names)

st.subheader('Prediction')
st.write(iris.target_names[prediction])
#st.write(prediction)

st.subheader('Prediction Probability')
st.write(prediction_proba)
```

Here is the error:

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ScriptRunner.scriptThread'.
Traceback:
File "c:\users\hp\anaconda3\anaconda\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 333, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 844, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 582, in initialize
    self.init_kernel()
File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 439, in init_kernel
    shell_stream = ZMQStream(self.shell_socket)
File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.io_loop = io_loop or IOLoop.current()
File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 116, in current
    loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\hp\anaconda3\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 265, in current
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
File "c:\users\hp\anaconda3\anaconda\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
```

Comment: This looks more like threading problem than streamlit

Comment: I have run your code in pycharm and it runs fine wihout any problem.

Comment: Did you run on terminal/prompt/shell: streamlit run main.py ?  Where 'main.py' is you source code filename? Your code is totally correct!

Comment: Looks like this was an Issue with an older version of `streamlit`: https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/744

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you wrote the script as a Jupyter notebook and you executed it right there in the Jupyter environment. The result of this is a warning box with the following content:

```
Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following command:

streamlit run /Users/TG/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py [ARGUMENTS]
```

It is more than tempting to copy this command and paste it to the command line.

But the thing is that this command does NOT work. Instead, executing it from the command line throws the errors you have encountered.

The remedy is this:

- Export the Jupyter notebook as an executable script (with `.py` as the filename extension), e.g. with the name `myscript.py`.
- Run this script from the command line with `streamlit run myscript.py` (after changing into the directory where the script is located).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import asyncio

def get_or_create_eventloop():
    try:
        return asyncio.get_event_loop()
    except RuntimeError as ex:
        if "There is no current event loop in thread" in str(ex):
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
            return asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```